# Excel VBA Show/Hide table columns based on a specified cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show a number of columns in a table based on a number vale in cell C11 on the same worksheet.

The data is currently in a table but if it helps, it doesn't have to be.

Cell C11 contains a number of weeks i.e. "6", range "Headers" include the week week number (this range is the header range of "Table1".

The number of columns is never a fixed amount, it is dynamic based on the value of C11.

I've tried two scripts so far but neither do anything:

1 -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rHdr As Range, rHdrs As Range
Dim strFirstAddr As String
If Target.Address <> "$C$11" Then Exit Sub
Set rHdr = Range("Headers").Find(Target.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
If Not rHdr Is Nothing Then
    strFirstAddr = rHdr.Address
    Set rHdrs = rHdr
    Do
        Set rHdrs = Application.Union(rHdrs, rHdr)
        Set rHdr = Range("Headers").FindNext(rHdr)
    Loop Until rHdr.Address = strFirstAddr
    Range("Headers").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    rHdrs.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

2 -

```
Sub HideColumns()
Dim p As Range

    For Each p In Range("Headers").Cells
        If p.Value < C11 Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next p
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know if it works? I don't really understand your approach but this works for me. Just specify your controlCell and tableToHide (the table you are trying to control) at the top of the macro.

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim controlCell As Range, tableToHide As Range
    Set controlCell = Range("G1")
    Set tableToHide = Range("Table1")
    
    If Target = controlCell Then
        tableToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        For i = controlCell.Value To tableToHide.Columns.Count
            tableToHide.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

If your controlCell isn't changed manually, you can't use Worksheet_change, you can instead try Worksheet_calculate, like so:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error GoTo errorHandling
        Dim controlCell As Range, tableToHide As Range
        Set controlCell = Range("G1")
        Set tableToHide = Range("Table1")
        
        tableToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        For i = controlCell.Value To tableToHide.Columns.Count
            tableToHide.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next i
errorHandling:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This macro doesn't check for target, so any time the worksheet recalculates for any reason, this macro will run. I also modified the code so that when the controlCell contains "1", 0 columns will show, if it contains "2", 1 column will show etc.

Comment: This works to an extent.  If I manually change cell C11 (you put it as G1) then it works, but the cell is based on a formula looking at a different sheet and when that changes, the columns don't show/hide automatically.  If there anything I can do for that?  Also, column 1 is always shown and it outside of the table, so is there a way to do something like Range("Table1" & - 1) or controlCell.Value(-1) + 1 so that the first column in Table1 only starts to show when the value in C11 is 2?

Comment: @KeithK Hi. Thanks for letting me know. I modified the code so that the columns only start showing if controlCell is 2 or more and added another solution in case your controlCell isn't changed manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check each column.  As your data is in a table then the column headers must be unique.

I guess you could use `On Error Resume Next` and try to hide the column - if the column doesn't exist an error occurs and is ignored.

I prefer to avoid any errors, so search for the column first and hide it if it exists.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$11" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1") 'Table1 on Sheet1 in workbook containing this code.
            .Range.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide all columns in table.
            If Not .HeaderRowRange.Find(What:=Target, _
                                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext) Is Nothing Then 'Does required column exist?
                .ListColumns(Target).Range.EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide required column.
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because "the cell is based on a formula looking at a different sheet" as  you said in your comment to andrewb.  The `Worksheet_Change` event won't fire in that instance.  If you put the code in the sheet where you do change the value then it should work (and change `Target.Address` to the cell you change.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this but for some reason it still isn't working and neither does it throw an error.